# Google maps navigation doesn't stay in status bar anymore

Tags: google-maps-navigation

When using google maps navigation I remember there used to be a constant notification item which let you switch back to navigation easily. This is not showing for me anymore and I can't find a setting to turn it back on.

Has this feature been removed or is there still a way to turn it back on?

Answer (score 0):

I had notifications disabled for the maps app. :0

The app still closes when i press close all apps. Don't think it used to do that earlier. But at least I can switch to it easily.